# Stream VOB files from DvD rips over my network

Tags: dvd, stream, upnp, dlna

Ive got some ripped dvd's in VOB format on my server. I want to stream these to another device I.e. another pc with VLC across my network. How?

Answer (score 2):

On the server side:

```
vlc -I http --http-src /path/to/your/vobs
```

By this will serve videos using HTTP over port 8080, which might not be terribly efficient. If this becomes an issue, take a look at this superuser question for RTSP solution: [Using VLC as RTSP server](https://superuser.com/questions/85170/using-vlc-as-rtsp-server).

VLC can also act as a client for your vobs:

```
vlc http://localhost:8080/filename.vob
```

assuming /path/to/your/vobs/filename.vob exists and is playable by VLC.

**Note!** I could not get this to work with files that have spaces in their names.